# How can aqueous KOH give alcohol by SN2 of alkyl halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, halides, nucleophilic-substitution

I ask this because S<sub>N</sub>2 requires a strong nucleophile, and I have read $\ce{OH-}$ isn't a strong nucleophile in a polar protic solvent like water. So, how can $\ce{OH-}$ replace, say $\ce{I-}$ from $\ce{CH3I}$ (methyl iodide)?

Comment: Even though its weaker in protic solvents, I won't say its  not a strong nucleophile.

Comment: With methyl iodide there is no opportunity for E2 elimination. Unhindered primary halides (Cl,Br,I) favor SN2 over E2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are considering a particular S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction, you have to consider the nucleophilicity as well as the **nature of the leaving group** of both the groups.

Here as you mentioned, $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{I-}$  (and other halide ions, except $\ce{F-}$, which is a very bad nucleophile) have comparable nucleophilicity in protic solvents. But, as for their leaving nature, $\ce{I-}$ (as well as other halides) is far more better leaving group than $\ce{OH-}$, because we know **weak bases are better leaving groups**. That is why the reaction is feasible.